# Batch rename files using REN in Windows 7 (adding prefix)

Tags: file, cmd, rename, prefix

I have figured out how to edit batches of files using `REN` in Windows 7 Command Prompt.  However, this time, I am trying to add a prefix to all files but I am unable to do it. All files are tif files.

For instance, files are located in C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test_Folder

Files inside each folder begin with 9.

Each file has 5 digits (i.e 90200, 90201, 90202).

I am trying to add a 0 (zero) in front of each file name and change it to 090200, 090201, 090203....

I tried:

```
FOR %v IN (?????.tif) DO REN %v 0%v
```

I also tried:

```
FOR %%a in (*.tif) DO REN "%%a" "0%a"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 30):

This one is simpler ...

```
forfiles /M *.tif /C "cmd /c ren @file 0@file"
```

Source: https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-file-extensions-bulk/

Comment: Upvoted. In Win 8, forfiles utility can be used as if we use DIR command is used on command prompt, that is, there is no need to write bat file, which is excellent. However, when used wrong, this can go into INFINITE LOOP, be aware, for example, already some files are already with 0, it happened to me.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
 for %a in (9????) do ren %a 0%a
```

```
C:\temp\test>for %a in (9????) do ren %a 0%a

C:\temp\test>ren 90200 090200

C:\temp\test>ren 90201 090201

C:\temp\test>ren 90202 090202

C:\temp\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4BF5-D156

 Directory of C:\temp\test

     04/02/2013  11:40 AM    <DIR>          .
     04/02/2013  11:40 AM    <DIR>          ..
     04/02/2013  11:36 AM                 4 090200
     04/02/2013  11:36 AM                 4 090201
     04/02/2013  11:36 AM                 4 090202
                    3 File(s)             12 bytes


               2 Dir(s)  86,883,287,040 bytes free
```

Comment: Stanley, I think I must be doing something wrong. I tried what you said but I got "[directory]" was unexpected at this time.  See below:   FOR "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TEST_FOLDER" %a in (9????) do ren %a 0%a  Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Stanley, I also tried: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TEST_FOLDER>for %a in (9????) do ren %a 0%a However, it did not work either

Comment: When I run that in Windows 8 in a regular command prompt, I get "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Nothing has opened any of the files.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to renaming files in folders and subfolders:

```
FOR /r "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test_Folder" %%a in (9*.tif) DO REN "%%~a" "0%%~nxa"
```

Comment: HI Endoro,I tried it but it did not work.  I got: %%a was unexpected at this time

Comment: On the command line you must type: `FOR /r "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test_Folder" %a in (9*.tif) DO REN "%~a" "0%~nxa"`. Only one `%`, and `%%` in a batch file!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! Problem solved. I had to slightly modify it and this is what worked for me:

```
FOR /r "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test_Folder" %a in (9*.tif) DO REN "%~a" "0%~nxa"
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This snippet code will help to remove "ab" of all file in folder:

```
FOR /r "folderName" %a in (ab*.txt) DO set fname=%~nxa & REN "%~a"  "%fname:~3%"
```

If the FolderName have some file like ab1.txt, ab2.txt
The result will be 1.txt, 2.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use Windows PowerShell

To open PowerShell, open the folder where the files are, make sure NO FILES are selected.
Find an empty area of the File area, and hold Shift + Right Click and select Open PowerShell window here

and use this formula:
dir | Rename-Item -Newname {$_.name -replace "90", "090"}.

To open PowerShell, open the folder where the files are, make sure NO FILES are selected.
Find an empty area of the File area, and hold Shift + Right Click and select Open PowerShell window here.

When the powerShell window opens it will have a part line of text which is the directory where the files are
PS X:\Main Folder\Folder Name\Folder Name> (This depends on how many folders/ sub folders you have the files in)
just after the > the cursor will be flashing.

Copy this command:  dir | Rename-Item -Newname {$_.name -replace "90", "090"}

Then paste it to where the cursor is flashing, then hit enter.

The files should now all have the 0 in front of the 9.

The limitation may be, if you have a file like 90909 you may end up with 0900909.

You could then, with Powershell still open use this command:

dir | Rename-Item -Newname {$_.name -replace "900", "90"}

That should fix that easily.

That's about the easiest way I know how to do that sort of thing.

I have mp3 files and it works a charm there.

This instruction will work with any file type.