# Rename A Group Of Files

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I need to rename a group of files in the same folder.
When I try to run the batch file,  it doesn't work correctly:

```
  `ren *.txt Updated_*.txt`
```

The file names contain date_names_location.txt, examples are below

`08232013_name1_nyc.txt`
`08212013_name1_nyc.txt`
`08232013_name1_la.txt`
`08212013_name1_la.txt`

When I run the batch file I get back:
`Updated_1_name1_nyc.txt`
      instead of 
 'Updated_08232013_name1_nyc.txt'

Any ideas on how to fix?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren "%%a" "Updated_%%a"
```

Answer (score 1):

REN has no insert mode, so it just replaces the beginning of your file names. Try the solution provided here 
[Batch renaming files using Windows 7 REN (adding prefix)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771714/batch-renaming-files-using-windows-7-ren-adding-prefix)